# Twilio video calls from mobile

Tags: reactjs, mobile, twilio, twilio-api, videochat

I'm facing an issue with the remote participant of Twilio video call container width.

I need to control both of views when it come to the mobile and the desktop, but the result is keeps showing as like the attached image.

[image]

I've tried to pass to the `Video.connect(token, {video: {width: 300, height: 300}})` but it's also not working.

Also when I'm trying to rotate the mobile into a landscape mood it working as expected like the desktop participant view, could any one please help me with that ?

Also those screenshots describe what I'm saying, portrait mood

[image]

Landscape mood

[image]

Comment: What have you done to try to control this, other than trying to use media constraints? Have you tried styling the videos with CSS? In the JavaScript, you can read the dimensions of the video track, have you considered trying to use that to adjust the page layout?

Comment: Hello Philnash,

I'm looking for a programmatic way to fix this, however when I tried to set a fixed width and height with the css if the user is from mobile the viewport is not fitting the user.

however, if you please could provide a code example to fully get your point it will be a pleasure.

Comment: My question is, what have you tried. I can’t really provide a code sample without more context from you. How are these videos laid out on the page right now? Have you considered just setting a fixed height in the CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my issue with adding a static height to the video element itself and adding an `object-fit: contain` to it.